# Playing random sound from raw folder with fisher yates shuffle algorithm on android

Tags: android, algorithm

please help me, I want to play the sound of raw folder android studio  random  using yate fisher shuffle algorithm with a single button.
I use this code:

```
public void playSound() {
    MediaPlayer mp;
    int[] rawSoal = {R.raw.al, R.raw.fear, R.raw.love};
    shuffleArray(rawSoal);
    for (int i = 0; i < rawSoal.length; i++) ;
    try {

        Random random = new Random();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, rawSoal[random.nextInt(rawSoal.length)]);
        mp.start();
        mp.release();

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("ERROR", "Media Player", e);
        mp = null;
    }
}
```

Implementing Fisher–Yates shuffle

```
static void shuffleArray(int[] ar) {
    Random rnd = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
    for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
        int a = ar[index];
        ar[index] = ar[i];
        ar[i] = a;
    }

}
```

The button for the call:

plybtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            playSound();
            mp.release();

        }
    });
```

Comment: whats is the problem you are getting using above code

Comment: when running, unfortunately, has stopped

Comment: Why are you using this : for (int i = 0; i < rawSoal.length; i++) ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think because you are releasing the MediaPlayer just after start(). So audio is not playing. Release MediaPlayer  on audio completion.

Comment: thanks , now i can play random. but when I click on the play for the second time the first sound still play. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void playSound() {
    MediaPlayer mp;
    int[] rawSoal = {R.raw.al, R.raw.fear, R.raw.love};
    shuffleArray(rawSoal);
    try {
        int idx = new Random().nextInt(rawSoal.length);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, rawSoal[idx]);
        mp.start();
        mp.release();

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("ERROR", "Media Player", e);
        mp = null;
    }
}

static void shuffleArray(int[] arr)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
            // Swap
            int a = arr[index];
            arr[index] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = a;
        }
    }
```

Comment: still can not .

Comment: now i can play random. but when I click on the play for the second time the first sound still play. What should I do?

Comment: Call Shuffle method everytime you click on the button. .

Comment: I use one button to play all audio. but when I play for the second time, the first sound does not stop.

Comment: when you try to play second time. Stop media player if it is already running and release it then reassign data source and start your player. Hope it will work.